# Importing time series from SQL base into R

Tags: r, time-series

I have a number of regular daily measurements in a MySQL database that I'd like to manipulate using R.  When it's returned from RMySQL, it looks like this:

```
> memdata
        date    vsize
1  2011-04-22 3535.178
2  2011-04-23 5680.516
3  2011-04-24 5468.914
4  2011-04-25 4761.044
5  2011-04-26 4403.515
6  2011-04-27 4459.155 
7  2011-04-28 4889.884
8  2011-04-29 5290.908
9  2011-04-30 5370.952
> str(memdata)
'data.frame':   9 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ date : chr  "2011-04-22" "2011-04-23" "2011-04-24" "2011-04-25" ...
 $ vsize: num  3535 5681 5469 4761 4404 ...
```

Since many of the time series libraries expect `ts` objects, I'd like to convert the data frame into one, but there doesn't seem to be a straightforward way of doing that.  [This site](http://www.stat.pitt.edu/stoffer/tsa2/R_time_series_quick_fix.htm) has a lot of good examples, but none that deal with daily data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a better reference for that kind of stuff:

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/index.html

Take a look at the vignettes.

Edit 1 =========================================

To answer chl's question, I would do the following:

```
library(zoo)
memdata.zoo <- read.zoo(memdata)
```

However, the reason that I pointed to the vignettes is because it is required reading.  Trust me, I've screwed up enough code that I am well aware that I don't yet fully understand everything in those articles.    There's a lot of subtle stuff in there.

Also, if you use packages like`stl` and `decompose`, be careful to notice that what they want as a `frequency` and what `zoo` wants as a `frequency` may not be what you expect.     You'll simply have to play around with it, and refer back to the vignettes.

Comment: @chl, I updated the above to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for the added clarifications. (Incidentally, I deleted my comment while editing it.) So basically, I provided quite a similar solution, except yours seems more general with the use of `read.zoo`, and we can ensure `regular=T` in the option.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I missed something, you want to convert your data.frame into a suitable time-indexed series of measurement. In this case, you can use the [zoo](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/index.html) package as follows:

```
> library(zoo)
> memdata.ts <- with(memdata, zoo(vsize, date))
> str(memdata.ts)
‘zoo’ series from 2011-04-22 to 2011-04-30
  Data: Factor w/ 9 levels "3535.178","4403.515",..: 1 9 8 4 2 3 5 6 7
  Index:  Factor w/ 9 levels "2011-04-22","2011-04-23",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: As I understand it, `zoo` is for irregular time series.  Is there no way to manipulate a daily time series into a `ts`?

Comment: @septagram `zoo` handles regular series as well, see `?zooreg`, and it works like `ts`. Sorry, I should have been more explicit.